# Build system for shell scripts

Tags: shell-script, compiling

At my workplace, there is a Bash script which is used to list Oracle databases running on a farm. I have made some modifications to it, using some inlined Python code (ex: `python -c "import sys..."`).

It has grown considerably and it's prompted me to think about using a build system for the script. Ideally, the build system will let me write the python code in a separate file, and then put it all together in one unified script. One unified script will help to simplify deployment procedures.

Also the build system should remove any comments to reduce the size of the script, but that is probably the easiest part.

If nothing exists, I'll take the time to write one myself. I was thinking that even if there are generic build tools (language agnostic), then I'd like to use those.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are asking here, or what you want to happen. What is your question, specified as succinctly as possible?

Comment: Let me try to make this simpler. I have a script wrapper.sh, which references stuff.py. I want to say "build" and the build tool inlines the python code in a call as described in my post. The end result should be a 'program.sh' with all code inlined.

Comment: Why inline the code at all? That seems like a strange thing to do. It would likely be better to have clear separation between your Python code and your shell script.

Comment: The tool MUST modify environment variables in the calling / source / parent shell, which can only be done by calling `. script.sh`. Therefore, the wrapper script CANNOT be a python script.

Comment: You have not read my reply correctly, I am not suggesting that you should make your wrapper a Python script. I am suggesting that you do not inline Python code.

Comment: The point of the build system would be to inline the Python code. Otherwise I would just create multiple scripts and link them together with pipes and environment variables.

Comment: ...which seems the far preferable solution.

Comment: Sure, but then you would have to deploy >= 2 files per server. It's doable but that is not the point of my question.

Comment: If you are willing to build a convoluted system to do this, but are not willing to consider the (long solved, and far more sustainable) solution of shipping more than 1 file in your deployment, I think you're headed down the wrong path. Good luck though. :-)

Comment: And inlining arbitrary code into one master script is much "scarier," but that's hard to explain to people who don't know any better.

Comment: May want to look at `m4`, which is used to create customized autoconf shell scripts. http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Programming-in-M4

Answer (score 0):

I feel wrong answering this, but here you go:

The gist is that a Makefile is the right tool for this job, and you can get away from shell escaping with here-string syntax.

#### base_script.sh

```
# some script...

xargs -0 python -c <<'PYTHON_SCRIPT_asdlfkjhsldjkhf'
PYTHON_SCRIPT_asdlfkjhsldjkhf

# more script ...
```

#### Makefile

```
merged_script.sh: base_script.sh python_script.py
    { sed -ne '0,/PYTHON_SCRIPT_/p' base_script.sh; \
      sed -e SOME_REGEX_TO_STRIP_COMMENTS python_script.py; \
      sed -ne '/^PYTHON_SCRIPT_/,999999999p' base_script.sh; \
    } > merged_script.sh
```

Basically that grabs the top half of the shell script, then splices in the python script, then attaches the bottom half of the script.  The python script is placed in a here-string, so you don't have to worry about any shell escaping.  You do need to make sure that string doesn't occur in the python code, but that shouldn't be a real problem.  You also have to keep the python script shorter than the max arguments limit, but you had that problem already.

Writing the regex to strip python comments is left as an exercise.

The sed commands to grab the upper and lower half of the script are sloppy, and could be replaced with some other utility script to splice files.  I'd suggest writing it in python since thats what you're comfortable with.